# NgSpice Installation

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, vlsi, linuxthreads, ngspice

I'm encountering an error while trying to compile ngspice, and I'm seeking assistance in resolving it. When compiling the bsimbulk module, I'm encountering the following error:

```
In file included from bsimbulk.c:8:
bsimbulkdefs.h:12976:27: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
12976 | #define bsimbulknumStates 0
| ^
bsimbulkdefs.h:13252:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘bsimbulknumStates’
13252 | bsimbulknumStates
| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[5]: *** [Makefile:495: bsimbulk.lo] Error 1
```

It seems to be related to a macro definition in bsimbulkdefs.h, and a lot of other header files have the same error 'expected identifier before numeric constant'. I'm unsure about how to resolve it. Can someone please provide guidance on how to troubleshoot and fix this issue?

I did try commenting out that the line '#define bsimbulknumStates 0' But I am not sure if that is the best thing to do

Comment: I can't even find the files mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently facing this issue as well,
but I bypassed this issue by replacing

`#define bsimbulknumStates 0` with `#define bsimbulknumStates false`

I don't know, is it a good option or not.
Anyone guide us why we are getting this error

```
In file included from bsimbulk.c:8:
bsimbulkdefs.h:12976:27: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
12976 | #define bsimbulknumStates 0
      |                           ^
bsimbulkdefs.h:13252:5: note: in expansion of macro 'bsimbulknumStates'
13252 |     bsimbulknumStates
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[5]: *** [Makefile:496: bsimbulk.lo] Error 1
```

After doing it, I am getting more this type of error but i resolving all like this